# How do i enter 10 numbers in array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to c++. It is necessary that the input source data and output the results to implement in the main function (use operator switch).
I need to enter 10 numbers in array in case 1. How do I enter 10 numbers in array in case 1?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Array {
  int SIZE; //array size
  int *mass; //array name
  public: 

  Array(int = 0); 

  Array(const Array &ob); 

  void set_mass(int ,int ); 

  int get_mass(int)const; 

  void show_mass(void) const; 
  ~Array(); 
};


Array :: ~Array(){ 
  delete [] mass; 
}


Array::Array(const Array &ob):SIZE(ob.SIZE)
{
  mass = new int [SIZE];
  if(!mass) exit(1);

  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++) 
    mass[i]=ob.mass[i];
}

Array::Array(int N){
  if(N < 0) {cout<<"Size error!!!!\n"; return;}

  N=10;
  SIZE = N;
  mass = new int[SIZE];
  if(!mass) exit(1);

  for(int i = 0;i < SIZE; i++) {
    mass[i] = i+1;
  }
}

void Array::set_mass(int i,int x)
{ 
  mass[i] = (i >= 0 && i <SIZE) ? x :0; 
}

int Array::get_mass(int i) const
{ 
  return (i >= 0 && i < SIZE) ? mass[i] : 0; 
}

void Array::show_mass( void ) const{ 
  for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout<<"["<<i<<"]="<<mass[i]<<endl;

}


int menu()   //menu
{
  cout<<"Enter: "<<endl;
  cout<<"1 - Array"<<endl;
  cout<<"2 - Show"<<endl;
  cout<<"0 - Quit"<<endl;
  int z;
  cin»z;
  return z;
}


void main()
{
  int SIZE;
  Array *mass[10];
  while (int z=menu())
  {

    switch(z)
    {

      case 1:
        {

          cout<<"Enter 10 numbers: ";

          break;
        }

      case 2:
        {
          for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
            Array A1;
            A1.show_mass();
          }
          break;
        }

      default:
        {
          cout<<"Error"<<endl;
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  getch();
}
```

Comment: homework? Investigate `cin` and `for` or `while` loops

Comment: Make a loop and input numbers. 
And learn proper indentation.

Comment: Fixed indentation of source code.  Hopefully, this can get some on topic help now

Comment: @OP: please try to explain your requirements better, they're hard to understand.  If you turn this into a decent question I'll take a crack at it

Comment: There is lots of confusion in your code. You have things to fix even before you try an input ten numbers into an array. First confusion, which array? You have an array here `Array *mass[10];` and you have an array here `mass = new int [SIZE];`. I doubt you need both, so which is the correct one? I suspect that what you really need is to replace `Array *mass[10];` with `Array mass(10);`. With this change you will have one Array object which contains an array of 10 masses. Does that sound right? I don't think anyone can answer this question until you clear up which array you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a Home work question!
Anyways 
write a separate method

```
void GetTenNumbers(int arr[]){  
    for(int counter =0; counter <10; counter ++){  
        cout<<"Enter number ";  
        cin>> arr[counter];  
    }  
}
```

and do something like this

```
case 1: 
{
  cout<<"Enter 10 numbers: ";
  GetTenNumbers(arr);
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several parts to what you want to do and based on your code, you seem to be a complete beginner.

Your best bet is to research stringstreams.  You can also checkout scanf.  As far as putting data into your array class, why not just use std::array or std::deque?